# swagger codegen missing attributes with allOf

Tags: swagger, swagger-codegen

We are using the latest swagger-codegen-cli (currently v2.4.28) to generate a python client from a swagger yaml file.   We use `allOf` throughout our specification to re-use definitions across multiple types of response objects.  When generating a python client we notice that model classes generated seem to be missing any attributes defined in the first `allOf` reference.

The specification is valid, and there are no errors or warnings generated that would indicate a problem so I am not sure if this is a bug or if we've misunderstood the intended usage.

Here is a minimal example that illustrates the problem.

```yaml
swagger: '2.0'
info:
    version: "0.1.0"
    title: Sample
host: localhost:8080
schemes:
    - https
basePath: /sample/v1
paths:
    /info:
        get:
            summary: Get Info
            operationId: getInfo
            produces:
                - application/json
            tags:
                - Info
            responses:
                200:
                    description: Information Response
                    schema:
                      $ref: "#/definitions/InfoResponse"
                default:
                    description: Unexpected error
definitions:
    InfoResponse:
        type: object
        allOf:
          - $ref: "#/definitions/Part1"
          - $ref: "#/definitions/Part2"
          - $ref: "#/definitions/Part3"
    Part1:
        type: object
        properties:
            a:
                type: integer
            b:
                type: integer
    Part2:
        type: object
        properties:
            c:
                type: string
            d:
                type: string
    Part3:
        type: object
        properties:
            e:
                type: string
            f:
                type: string
```

We use the following command to generate the python client.

```
java -jar swagger-codegen-cli-2.4.28.jar generate -l python -i api-specification.yaml -o codegen
```

The python model class for the `InfoResponse` object has the following `swagger_types` and `attribute_map` values.

```py
    swagger_types = {
        'c': 'str',
        'd': 'str',
        'e': 'str',
        'f': 'str'
    }

    attribute_map = {
        'c': 'c',
        'd': 'd',
        'e': 'e',
        'f': 'f'
    }
```

As you can see, the two attributes from the Part1 reference are missing (i.e., "a", and "b").  If I reorder the references so that Part2 is first then "c" and "d" go missing and "a" and "b" are present.  Like this:

```
    InfoResponse:
        type: object
        allOf:
          - $ref: "#/definitions/Part2"
          - $ref: "#/definitions/Part1"
          - $ref: "#/definitions/Part3"
```

It would appear as though the first reference in the list is always ignored.  Is this a bug, a template problem, are the definitions not specified correctly, or am I not understanding how this is supposed to work?

Comment: It's a codegen bug. Open an issue at https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues or check if there's an existing issue. Also try [openapi-generator](https://openapi-generator.tech/) instead of Swagger Codegen, maybe it doesn't have this issue.